# Permutations/Combinations with Categories

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have 3 categories. Each of these categories has three options.

Category 1 options: A, B, C

Category 2 options: D, E, F

Category 3 options: G, H, I

So a permutation of these may look like this: A E H

I am trying to find the number of permutations with these categories.

This looks like a special kind of permutations problem and I am not sure how to approach it, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $3$ ways to choose the letter from each category, and then $3!$ ways of permuting them, giving a total of $$3^3\times 3!=162$$ ways.

Comment: What if the categories all had a different number of options?

Comment: @gegs921 You were to multiply the number of options from each category.

Comment: Oh I see, instead of 3^3. Thanks so much!

Comment: @gegs921 Yep, you’re welcome.